# Rails 4 - how to give alias names to includes() and joins() in active record querying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, arel

How can I give an alias name for e.g. `includes()`?
Following is given:

- User: active record model
- Student: active record model, inherits from User (STI)
- Teacher: active record model, inherits from User (STI)
- Project: active record model

Here some examples:

**FIRST CASE (more STI associations)**

```
Project.all.includes(:students, :teachers).order('teachers_projects.name ASC') # order on teachers
Project.all.includes(:students, :teachers).order('users.name ASC') # order on students
```

Rails uses automatically alias name `teachers_projects` for `:teachers` in the SQL. How can I overwrite this, so that I can use alias name `teachers` instead of `teachers_projects` in the SQL? `:students` gets alias name `users`.

**This examples fails:**

```
Project.all.includes(:students, :teachers).order('teachers.name ASC')
Project.all.includes(:students, :teachers).order('students.name ASC')
Project.all.includes(:students, :teachers).order('students_projects.name ASC')
```

**SECOND CASE (one STI association)**

If I use only `:students` (without `:teachers`) in method `includes()`, Rails uses name alias of the STI base class name `users` (without `_projects` attached) for `:students`:

```
Project.all.includes(:students).order('users.name ASC') # order on students
```

**This examples fails:**

```
Project.all.includes(:students).order('students.name ASC')
Project.all.includes(:students).order('students_projects.name ASC')
```

**QUESTION**

Might exist something like:

```
Project.all.includes(:students).alias(students: :my_alias)
```

**RAILS ALIAS TRACKER**

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/alias_tracker.rb#L59

**TESTING APP**

https://gist.github.com/phlegx/add77d24ebc57f211e8b

https://github.com/phlegx/rails_query_alias_names

Comment: Have you tried something like Project.joins(:teachers).where......

Comment: If you get the answer, please _notify_ me, so that I can also see the answer.

Comment: Can you also give a Gist to show the models definitions, migrations and some data.. So that I can set up, and try to do ?

Comment: @phlegx Is your project on public GitHub ?

Comment: Have a look at this answer from a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25856700/488195. He is using arel to handle the aliases in a way that might help you. I'm posting my approach as an answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take another approach to this issue: instead of trying to control the alias names on your queries with an `.alias` method, I'll let Rails / Arel handle that and just look the correct table name (aliased or not) up whenever there is need for it within a scope.

Add this helper method to your model, that you'd be able to call from an scope to know if the scope is being used within a `JOIN` that has the table name aliased (multiple joins on the same table), or if on the other hand the scope has no alias for the table name.

```
def self.current_table_name
  current_table = current_scope.arel.source.left

  case current_table
  when Arel::Table
    current_table.name
  when Arel::Nodes::TableAlias
    current_table.right
  else
    fail
  end
end
```

This uses [`current_scope`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/ClassMethods/current_scope) as the base object to look for the arel table. I'm calling `source` on that object to obtain an [`Arel::SelectManager`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/SelectManager) that in turn will give you the current table on the `#left`. There are two options there: either you have there an `Arel::Table` (no alias, table name is on `#name`) or you have an `Arel::Nodes::TableAlias` with the alias on its `#right`.

Now you only need to use that on your `order` statements (untested):

```
Project.all.includes(:students, :teachers).order("#{current_table_name}.name ASC")
Project.all.includes(:students, :teachers).order("#{current_table_name}.name ASC")
Project.all.includes(:students, :teachers).order("#{current_table_name}.name ASC")
```

Related questions:

- [ActiveRecord query with alias'd table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685149/activerecord-query-with-aliasd-table-names) (where I first used this approach).
- [Join the same table twice with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921729/join-the-same-table-twice-with-conditions)

Comment: I gave an answer in one of the questions you refer. You can simplify this a bit. `current_scope.table` is the same as `current_scope.arel.source.left` (perhaps not in Rails < 4.2.2?). And if you use the `"Arel syntax"` you don't have to get the bare table name. E.g. use it like this: `at = current_scope.table`, and then `at[:the_column_name].asc` and `Arel` do all for you. (perhaps you have to add a `.to_sql`, but I think that Rails will handle it for you)

Answer (score 3):

Arel does actually have an alias method.

```
student_alias = Student.arel_table.alias(:my_student_table_alias)
```

caveat: this will require you to use even more handcrafted Arel and do the join manually. And the joins in Arel can get a bit complicated if you're not used to them.

```
student_alias_join = student_alias.create_on(
  Project.arel_table[:primary_key].eq(student_alias[:project_id])
)

Project.joins(
  Project.arel_table.create_join(
    student_alias, student_alias_join, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin
  )
).order(...)
```

Something like this should do it.
Of course putting this into some Class method with `:my_student_table_alias` as parameter would make it more tidy and reusable as this would look a bit messy in a controller.