# ActiveRecord query with alias'd table names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

Using model concerns which include scopes, what is the best way to write these knowing that nested and/or self-referencing queries are likely?

In one of my concerns, I have scopes similar to these:

```
scope :current, ->(as_at = Time.now) { current_and_expired(as_at).current_and_future(as_at) }
scope :current_and_future, ->(as_at = Time.now) { where("#{upper_bound_column} IS NULL OR #{upper_bound_column} >= ?", as_at) }
scope :current_and_expired, ->(as_at = Time.now) { where("#{lower_bound_column} IS NULL OR #{lower_bound_column} <= ?", as_at) }

def self.lower_bound_column
  lower_bound_field
end
def self.upper_bound_column
  upper_bound_field
end
```

And is referred to via has_many's, example: `has_many :company_users, -> { current }`

If an ActiveRecord query is made which refers to a few models that include the concern, this results in an 'ambiguous column name' exception which makes sense.

To help overcome this, I change the column name helper methods to now be

```
def self.lower_bound_column
  "#{self.table_name}.#{lower_bound_field}"
end
def self.upper_bound_column
   "#{self.table_name}.#{upper_bound_field}"
end
```

Which works great, until you require self-referencing queries. Arel helps mitigate these issues by aliasing the table name in the resulting SQL, for example:

`LEFT OUTER JOIN "company_users" "company_users_companies" ON "company_users_companies"."company_id" = "companies"."id"`

and

`INNER JOIN "company_users" ON "users"."id" = "company_users"."user_id" WHERE "company_users"."company_id" = $2`

The issue here is that `self.table_name` no longer refers to the table name in the query. And this results in the tongue in cheek hint: `HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "company_users_companies"`

In an attempt to migrate these queries over to Arel, I changed the column name helper methods to:

```
def self.lower_bound_column
  self.class.arel_table[lower_bound_field.to_sym]
end
def self.upper_bound_column
  self.class.arel_table[upper_bound_field.to_sym]
end
```

and updated the scopes to reflect:

`lower_bound_column.eq(nil).or(lower_bound_column.lteq(as_at))`

but this just ported the issue across since `self.class.arel_table` will always be the same regardless of the query.

I guess my question is, is how do I create scopes that can be used in self-referencing queries, which require operators such as `<=` and `>=`?

---

## Edits

I have created a basic application to help showcase this issue.

```
git clone git@github.com:fattymiller/expirable_test.git
cd expirable_test
createdb expirable_test-development
bundle install
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
rails s
```

---

## Findings and assumptions

1. Works in sqlite3, not Postgres. Most likely because Postgres enforces the order of queries in the SQL?

Comment: I have a similar problem. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595636/rails-4-how-to-give-alias-names-to-includes-and-joins-in-active-record-que

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, well, well. After quite a big time looking through the sources of `Arel`, `ActiveRecord` and `Rails` issues (it seems this is not new), I was able to find the way to access the current `arel_table` object, with its `table_aliases` if they are being used, inside the `current` scope at the moment of its execution.

That made possible to know if the scope is going to be used within a `JOIN` that has the table name aliased, or if on the other hand the scope can be used on the real table name.

I just added this method to your `Expirable` concern:

```
def self.current_table_name
  current_table = current_scope.arel.source.left

  case current_table
  when Arel::Table
    current_table.name
  when Arel::Nodes::TableAlias
    current_table.right
  else
    fail
  end
end
```

As you can see, I'm using [`current_scope`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/ClassMethods/current_scope) as the base object to look for the arel table, instead of the prior attempts of using `self.class.arel_table` or even `relation.arel_table`, which as you said remained the same regardless of where the scope was used. I'm just calling `source` on that object to obtain an [`Arel::SelectManager`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/SelectManager) that in turn will give you the current table on the `#left`. At this moment there are two options: that you have there an `Arel::Table` (no alias, table name is on `#name`) or that you have an `Arel::Nodes::TableAlias` with the alias on its `#right`.

With that table_name you can revert to your first attempt of `#{current_table_name}.#{lower_bound_field}` and `#{current_table_name}.#{upper_bound_field}` in your scopes:

```
def self.lower_bound_column
  "#{current_table_name}.#{lower_bound_field}"
end

def self.upper_bound_column
  "#{current_table_name}.#{upper_bound_field}"
end

scope :current_and_future, ->(as_at = Time.now) { where("#{upper_bound_column} IS NULL OR #{upper_bound_column} >= ?", as_at) }
scope :current_and_expired, ->(as_at = Time.now) { where("#{lower_bound_column} IS NULL OR #{lower_bound_column} <= ?", as_at) }
```

This `current_table_name` method seems to me to be something that would be useful to have on the AR / Arel public API, so it can be maintained across version upgrades. What do you think?

If you are interested, here are some references I used down the road:

- A [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921729/join-the-same-table-twice-with-conditions), answered with a ton of code, that you could use instead of your beautiful and concise Ability.
- This [Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12770) and this [other one](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12982).
- And [the commit on your test app](https://github.com/fattymiller/expirable_test/commit/b3380c80b22ffd481962bb61c74ab7b629adbca4) on github that made tests green!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and effort with this issue! My research showed very similar suggestions - one even suggesting to parse the generated SQL :| I would think that there would be a reason that they have not included something similar to what you suggest, but it would definitely be worth a discussion for you to have with the Rails team to see if they would consider merging your solution into core - your name would be against a pretty nice chunk of code for future coders to see..

Comment: I'm glad to help and I can say I also learned a lot with this one! Quite a challange :) I'll ask on the Rails issue if they'd consider a PR. Thanks!

Comment: @dgilperez, Hey.. what do you think about my modified approach? I would love to hear your suggestions..

Answer (score 2):

I have a slightly modified approach from @dgilperez, which uses the full power of Arel

```
def self.current_table_name
 current_table = current_scope.arel.source.left
end
```

now you could modify your methods with arel_table syntax

```
def self.lower_bound_column
 current_table[:lower_bound_field]
end

def self.upper_bound_column
  current_table[:upper_bound_field]
end
```

and use it query like this

```
 lower_bound_column.eq(nil).or(lower_bound_column.lteq(as_at))
```