# Rails 4: Dynamic table name possible in `where` on `has_many :through`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, arel

I have an association:

```
has_many :regions_deployed, -> { where(taggings: { scope: 'deployed' }) },
:through => :taggings, :source => :choice_filter, :source_type => "Region"
```

This usually works, except when it is used in the `joins` clause of a named scope, chained to other named scopes that also join on `taggings`. Then Postgres aliases the table name `taggings`, but the `where(taggings: { scope: 'deployed' }` does not reflect that alias. How can I specify a dynamic table name inside `where`?

I think this question is closely related, but can't get it: [Join the same table twice with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921729/join-the-same-table-twice-with-conditions)