# How to compare a joined table with the source dynamically

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

### The Context

I have Five models: Reward, BrandSubscription, Brand, Tier and User.

- `Brand` has many `Tiers`.
- `BrandSubscription` belongs to a `Tier` and to `User`.
- `Reward` belongs to a `Tier`.
- `Tier` has an attribute named `order`. If a `BrandSubscription` have a tier of a higher order, it will also have all the lower tiers as well.
- A `BrandSubscription` can see all `Rewards` from all its `Tiers`, that are in this case the `Tier` that it belongs to and all its lower `Tiers`.

### The Problem

My problem is with the last item of the list above. I'm trying to get all rewards of a brand subscription.

The ideal way would be a `has_many :rewards` on the `BrandSubscription` entity, that would be `through: :tier`. On `Tier` I could have a `has_many :rewards`. The problem with this approach is that the rewards are not restricted to the current tier, but must include all rewards from the lower `order` tiers.

To achieve that, I put a scope on the `has_many :rewards` of the `Tier` model:

```
class Tier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  has_many :rewards

  has_many :with_lower_tiers, lambda {
    where(this_table[:order].gteq(that_table[:order]))
  }, through: :brand, source: :tiers

  has_many :achievable_rewards, through: :with_lower_tiers, source: rewards
end
```

The problem here, is with `this_table` and `that_table`. I need to make some kind of a join here, so I could have a comparison between the tables. The one approach I could make work was this:

```
class Tier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  has_many :rewards

  has_many :with_lower_tiers, lambda { |tier|
    where(current_scope.table[:order].lteq(tier.order))
  }, through: :brand, source: :tiers

  has_many :achievable_rewards, through: :with_lower_tiers, source: rewards
end
```

Here I use the tier owner object and get its order. The problem here is that I can't really rely on the `tier` argument. The follow query already breaks, because what is really passed as argument to the scope function is the "owner" entity of the query, in this case, `BrandSubscription`:

`BrandSubscription.joins(:with_lower_tiers)`

The SQL query I want to get is the following, where I can get all available rewards from a User. Note that I'm joining the `tiers` table twice, and the is precisely where I'm having troubles:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rewards.*
  FROM tiers
  INNER JOIN brand_subscriptions ON tiers.id = brand_subscriptions.tier_id
  INNER JOIN tiers tiers_reward ON tiers_reward.brand_id = tiers.brand_id
  INNER JOIN rewards ON tiers_reward.id = rewards.tier_id
  WHERE tiers_reward.order <= tiers.order
    AND brand_subscriptions.user_id = 1234
```

I believe some Arel may help but I really would love if I could rely entirely on the ActiveRecord for this, as the code would be much cleaner.

### References

I'm using the following links in order to try to solve this problem:

- [Join the same table twice with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921729/join-the-same-table-twice-with-conditions)
- https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-arel-to-compose-sql-queries
- http://jpospisil.com/2014/06/16/the-definitive-guide-to-arel-the-sql-manager-for-ruby.html
- https://gist.github.com/mildmojo/3724189
- http://jpospisil.com/2014/06/16/the-definitive-guide-to-arel-the-sql-manager-for-ruby.html
- [ActiveRecord query with alias'd table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685149/activerecord-query-with-aliasd-table-names/28821450#28821450)

Answer (score 0):

You could build the query yourself instead of relying on complicated has_many-through associations

```
class Reward < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tier
end

class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tiers
end

class Tier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  has_many :rewards

  # has_many :lower_tiers, ->(tier){ where('tiers.order < ?', tier.order) }, through: :brand, source: :tiers

  def lower_tiers
    Tier.where('brand_id = ? AND order < ?', brand_id, order)
  end

  def achievable_rewards
    Rewards.where('tier_id IN (?) OR tier_id = ?', lower_tiers.select(:id), id)
  end
end


class BrandSubscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tier

  def rewards
    tier ? tier.achievable_rewards : Reward.none
  end
end
```

Comment: This could work, but what I really need is everything in just one query. This solution would make 4 queries, and there's no way to use `include` to eager load everything. Thanks though.

Comment: Which are the 4 queries? There is one to get all related tiers ids and one to get all rewards.

Comment: The load of the brand subscription, then the brand subscription tier (because of the belongs_to), then the tier's brand (because of the belongs_to of the brand on the tier), then the tiers of the brand with the order where clause.

Comment: You are right. I optimized it to three queries: the brand subscription, the tier and finally the rewards. If the performance is an issue and the tiers are rarely changed you could denormalize the rewards-tiers relation?